# Java can't read Chinese character in correct coding

Tags: java, ios, macos, utf-8, appium

I use Mac OS X in 10.8.
My [Appium](http://appium.io/) Java test code need to read Chinese label from iOS app's accessibility label and accessibility label is Chinese character string，but when java read Chinese string to memory in incorrect coding.
My java source code save as "UTF-8";
My terminal is set to "UTF-8";

and sour code is similar below:

```
String correct_aid = "你好";
String got_aid = driver.findElement(By.name('sayHello')).getText();
if (got_aid.contains(correct_aid)) {
    System.out.println("Got accessibility label string is matched.");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Got accessibility label string is not matched.");
    System.out.println("Expected accessibility label is: [" + correct_aid + "]");
    System.out.println("Captured accessibility label is: [" + got_aid + "]")
}
```

and I got the result as below:

```
Got accessibility label string is not matched.
Expected accessibility label is: [你好]
Captured accessibility label is: [????]
```

It seems that, Java can print out the variable which created in java source code and the value is Chinese character string,
but can't convert the correct coding from reading a out source.

I also run "locale" in terminal and gets the result below:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

As you know, if the out source is a txt file, maybe change the coding to "UTF-8" when save it for fixing it, but now my out source is an iOS app so I can't fix the problem via change the out source coding.

Could you provide what others methods I can fix this problem?
Thanks so much.

Comment: If possible hex dump `got_aid` and post. It could be a UTF-16 issue, internally NSString used UTF-16.

Comment: Preferably, hex-dump the data produced by the iOS app

Comment: Hi Laune, this app is not problem in Chinese character as my another Mac machine is work well in Java read the Chinese string of the iOS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue and just added statement below to ~/.bash_profile

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

and then run command below to enable it.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

hope can help more guys who meets this problem.

Comment: this helps resolved my issue. but I can't understand why, the characters are coming from database, why is it related with `file.encoding` anyways?